# Plugin to hide admin menu (vertical menu bar)

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am learning to write WordPress plugin and testing out a simple case: hide the admin bar base on user role.  So far I have the following in my plugin file:

```
$hidemenu= new HideMenu();
class HideMenu
{
    function hideMenu() {
        add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , array($this, 'hideAdminBar'));
    }

    function hideAdminBar() {
            if (!(current_user_can("administrator")) 
                            return false;
    }
}
```

This is base on the example given in [WordPress reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/show_admin_bar).  Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: You need to call the class inside a function. This function has to be attached to the right hook. `'init'` for example. Much smarter would be to have a static init method inside the class that's calling the class once. Then handle the rest during your construct method where you add all sort of filters and functions to their appropriate hooks.

Comment: Can you show me in code what you mean?  Thanks...

Comment: Just take a look at php5 classes. Currently you're writing in php4 standard. Also take a look at `__construct()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the [WP Custom Admin Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-custom-admin-bar/) plugin?  At the very least it has some code chunks you can deconstruct to point you in the right direction.